Dividing a layer into 75 pixels equally using a JavaScript file in Adobe Photoshop
Consider my Code:
// Ensure a document is open
if (app.documents.length > 0) {
    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var originalLayer = doc.activeLayer; // Store reference to the original layer

    // Check if the layer is not the background layer
    if (!originalLayer.isBackgroundLayer) {
        var layerBounds = originalLayer.bounds;
        var layerWidth = layerBounds[2].as('px') - layerBounds[0].as('px'); // Convert bounds to pixels
        var layerHeight = layerBounds[3].as('px') - layerBounds[1].as('px'); // Convert bounds to pixels
        var segmentWidth = 75; // Width of each segment in pixels

        for (var x = 0; x < layerWidth; x += segmentWidth) {
            doc.activeLayer = originalLayer; // Reactivate the original layer
            // Create a selection for the segment
            var segmentRight = Math.min(x + segmentWidth, layerWidth);
            var selectionCoords = [
                [x, 0],
                [segmentRight, 0],
                [segmentRight, layerHeight],
                [x, layerHeight]
            ];

            // Check if the selection coordinates are valid
            if (isValidSelection(selectionCoords)) {
                doc.selection.select(selectionCoords);
                // Copy the selection to a new layer
                doc.selection.copy();
                var newLayer = doc.artLayers.add();
                doc.paste();
                newLayer.name = "Segment " + (x / segmentWidth + 1);

                // Deselect to avoid interference in the next loop
                doc.selection.deselect();
            } else {
                alert("Invalid selection coordinates.");
            }
        }
        alert("Layer divided into 25-pixel segments.");
    } else {
        alert("The active layer is the background layer and cannot be divided.");
    }
} else {
    alert("No document open.");
}

// Function to check if selection coordinates are valid
function isValidSelection(coords) {
    for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
        if (coords[i][0] < 0 || coords[i][1] < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

What am I trying to do?
I have a layer named Color. I want to create several layers of equal width 75px copying content from this layer using a JavaScript file.
For my document, my active Layer is a layer named Color. The layer has been partially [not fully] filled with pink color. Now, whenever I run this file, a layer named Segment 1 is created indeed, but after that an alert dialog box appears that says Could not complete the command because the selected layer is empty. I know where the problem is. I picked up 75 pixels of layer data from the extreme left from layer Color, pasted in to layer Segment 1 and created it. But when the loop runs for the second time, it considers Segment 1 as the active layer, which actually is not. So I explicitly added the line:
doc.activeLayer = originalLayer;

so that for every time the loop runs, the active layer is the layer named Color. But still the problem persists. Where have I done something wrong? I think I need to add some offset values.

what is diving a layer? also, you need to provide a context to what the piece of code you have supplied is doing instead of randomly telling people to read all of it and understand on their own. Also, please tell what are you trying to do ?

There seems to nothing wrong with your code. Are your running the correct file?

Oh, snap! I finally found a bug and solved it myself. Thank you!!!

@M.Riyan But problem still appears, when my layer is not entirely filled with content. I mentioned the concept of offset values. Is there anyway you can help?

In case you have a layer that has not been filled entirely by any content, it is necessary to use an offset pair of values.
A layer has its width and height only measured from its content. If the canvas size is 1920x1080, then a layer — having content only within the rectangle within the four coordinates (100,100), (100,200), (300,200) and (300,100) — will have definite layer_width and layer_height values that you can measure.
        var layerBounds = originalLayer.bounds;
        var layerX = layerBounds[0].as('px'); // X coordinate of the top-left corner of the layer
        var layerY = layerBounds[1].as('px'); // Y coordinate of the top-left corner of the layer

Here, in this code, layerX has a value of 100 [for my example] and layerY has a value of 100 too. Now, to find the layer_height and layer_width, I can simply follow your steps:
        var layerWidth = layerBounds[2].as('px') - layerX; // Width of the layer in pixels
        var layerHeight = layerBounds[3].as('px') - layerY; // Height of the layer in pixels

Thus, we have the offset values now, which can be written as:
        var offsetX = layerX;
        var offsetY = layerY;

and the code finally becomes changed at:
       var selectionCoords = [
                [x + offsetX, offsetY],
                [segmentRight + offsetX, offsetY],
                [segmentRight + offsetX, layerHeight + offsetY],
                [x + offsetX, layerHeight + offsetY]
       ];

That's it. Nothing else required.

In case of debugging, we can use the JavaScript alert() function to debug values.
